# How to make Maven deploy using a different, ad-hoc group Id?

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory

Some background:

- I have copied the master branch of an external github repository, not owned by me, into a personal repository
- This repo contains a Java project and uses **Maven** for building and compilation
- The group ID defined in all **pom.xml** files is **org.mylibrary** (let's assume)
- When deploying to Artifactory, the deployment is done to **myrepo/org/mylibrary/...**

I'd like to deploy instead to:

- **myrepo/org/myorganization/mylibrary**

but I would like to avoid editing all the **pom.xml** files, and replacing all lines containing:
`<groupId>org.mylibrary</groupId>`
with:
`<groupId>org.myorganization.mylibrary</groupId>`.

I'm configuring the deployment via the **distributionManagement** element:

```
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <name>releases</name>
  <id>deployment.credentials</id>
  <url>https://artifactory.lab.myorg.org/artifactory/myrepo</url>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

What's a clean way of solving this? Replacing the groupId definition in all pom.xml files does the trick, but, as said, that's something I want to avoid.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is another way. If these modules have a common parent, you can remove the groupId from everywhere but the parent (so inheriting it), but I don't think you can set the groupId from outside unless you put a suitable Maven property inside the groupId tag, which, again, would mean to modify all POMs.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to any repository, Artifactory utilizes the [layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-Configuration) that is configured for this repository. By default, for Maven repositories, Artifactory uses the "maven-default" layout.

I would recommend you to first add your requested layout and then [configure your repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-RepositoryConfigurationrepoConfig) with the newly created layout.

I hope this information is found helpful.